# JMeter Plugin - How to Listen to TestState

Tags: jmeter

I am working on developing a JMeter plugin. I'm trying to create an AbstractVisualizer that is capable of monitoring the current test state. However, implementing the TestStateListener doesn't seem to be working.

I'm testing this by creating a basic listener that has a login to output arbitrary info to JMeter's logging console. When a sample is sent through the Add function, a line is sent to the console. But nothing is ever triggered on the various TestState functions.  Is there something more structural I'm missing?

```
public class TestListener extends AbstractVisualizer
implements TestStateListener
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass(); 
    @Override
    public void add(SampleResult arg0) {
        log.info("add");
    }

    @Override
    public void clearData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public String getStaticLabel()
    {
        return "Test Listener";
    }

    @Override
    public String getLabelResource() {
        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    public void testEnded() {
        log.info("Test Ended");     
    }

    @Override
    public void testEnded(String arg0) {
        log.info("Test Ended");     
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted() {
        log.info("Test started");       
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(String arg0) {
        log.info("Test started");       
    }           

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it in 1 class. I have 2 classes:

The UI:

```
public class MonitorGui extends AbstractListenerGui
{
    // ...
    @Override
    public TestElement createTestElement() 
    {
        TestElement element = new Monitor();// <-- this is the backend
        modifyTestElement(element);
        return element;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then the backend goes like this:

```
public class Monitor extends AbstractListenerElement 
                     implements SampleListener, 
                                Clearable, Serializable,
                                TestStateListener, Remoteable,
                                NoThreadClone
{
    private static final String TEST_IS_LOCAL = "*local*";
    // ...
    @Override
    public void testStarted() 
    {
        testStarted(TEST_IS_LOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void testEnded() 
    {
        testEnded(TEST_IS_LOCAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void testStarted(String host) 
    {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

You may not need to implement `SampleListener` like I do, but probably other things are quite similar.

I based that implementation on a built-in pair of [ResultSaverGui](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/gui/ResultSaverGui.java) and [ResultCollector](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/ResultCollector.java) which are the components that are saving results into the file(s) for Simple Data Writer, Summary Report and so on.

Comment: This is the model I needed to look at. Thanks!