# Fork, adapt and build jmeter plugin

Tags: plugins, jmeter

I've been searching for help on building a new JMeter plugin under the listener category. I can either build it from scratch but, being a newbie, just want to fork an existing plugin from the standard library to start with.

I've copied a module from the standard library and made some changes but when using maven "mvn clean package", jmeter won't recognize the jar. Are there some steps I'm missing?

Comment: Follow this: https://www.jayway.com/2010/07/07/developing-jmeter-plugins-using-maven/ to create maven project
And then there was an earlier question on how to implement JMeter listener: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35110388/jmeter-plugin-how-to-listen-to-teststate/35110901#35110901. It's pretty straight forward, but you need a very specific classes / inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, that's really useful and got me part way to solving my issues. I found I was bringing in too many dependencies to my project, then by being explicit about the dependencies I needed found I had to add more. Andrey from the JMeter forum helped me out for the final mile.